# Windows Certification Authority Autoenrollment when Issuance Requirements is set

Tags: certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I have domain computers CA template which autoenrolls to machines without issues

I activated Issuance Requirements

[image]

I can automatically renew existing certificates, but cannot automatically/manyally to create new cert, i'm asked for Recovery agent certificate

[image]

I already Enrolled Enrollment Certificate to current user/computer account but wizard still shows it's missing

When for computers template, under Issuance requirements i select as below

[image]

My Enrollment agent cert is shown and i can install new cert manually,but cannot renew it

```
 Active Directory Certificate Services denied request 834 because One or more signatures did not include the required application or issuance policies.
The request is missing one or more required valid signatures. 0x8009480b (-2146875381 CERTSRV_E_SIGNATURE_REJECTED).  The request was for CN=machine,example.com.  Additional information: Denied by Policy Module  0x8009480b, The Computer Certificate Template requires 1 signatures, but only 0 were accepted.
```

Is there a way to automatically enroll/autoenroll certs when Number of authorized signatures option is enabled ?